# How can I get the secret link for a track posted to Soundcloud in Python?

Tags: python, api, hyperlink, private, soundcloud

I'm developing a simple app using Python where I can post tracks to my own Soundcloud account. I would like to get the 'Secret link' URL for a track that I post. For example, I get the most recent track like so:

```
track = client.get('/me/tracks', limit=1)[0]
```

The track is set to private. It suggests in the [Docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) that something like this should return the secret token:

```
client.get('/tracks/%d/secret-token' %track.id)
```

However, I get HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found. All the other subresources seem to work. This example code, for example, works as you would expect:

```
comments = client.get('/tracks/%d/comments' %track.id)

for comment in comments:
    print comment.body
```

I would have thought that, given that I have authenticated using my credentials, I would have access to this. Is this correct? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The [documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks) certainly mentions the API endpoint; but perhaps you need to `PUT` a token first?

Comment: Also, is the track *private*? As I understand it the secret code is only needed for private tracks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, it is private. Also using PUT with secret-token gives me the same error.

Comment: Okay, out of ideas then; this doesn't look like a Python problem in that case, you'd have to take that up with Soundcloud support I guess.

Comment: Does it work in the console? http://developers.soundcloud.com/console, if so you can always make regular web service requests you don't have to use the client.

Comment: @kreek Hi. No, I get the same problem using the console. The tooltip just says "This resource can only be used by the track owner", which is me. It would be nice to hear if anyone can get either the secret token or the embed code for one of their own private tracks.

Answer (score 1):

The /me/tracks endpoint returns a `Track` object that includes `secret_token` as well as the full uri `secret_uri`.

```
track = client.get('/me/tracks', limit=1)[0]
print "Secret Token: %s" %track.secret_token
print "Track URI: %s"  %track.secret_uri
```

I found I needed to include the `client_id` in the URI to avoid getting a 401.

*Note: this is undocumented so check with their support team before relying this in an application*